# Why am I receiving a "no ordering relation defined for complex numbers" error?

Tags: python, math, cubic

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16270941/whats-wrong-with-this-python-function-to-solve-cubic-equations) for some background. My main problem on that question was solved, and it was suggested that I ask another one for a second problem I'm having:

```
print cubic(1, 2, 3, 4)  # Correct solution: about -1.65
...
    if x > 0:
TypeError: no ordering relation is defined for complex numbers
print cubic(1, -3, -3, -1)  # Correct solution: about 3.8473
    if x > 0:
TypeError: no ordering relation is defined for complex numbers
```

Cubic equations with one real root and two complex roots are receiving an error, even though I am using the cmath module and have defined the cube root function to handle complex numbers. Why is this?

Comment: What is the value of `x`?

Comment: See the other question. x is an argument passed to the function that calculates the cube root.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Python's error messages are pretty good, as these things go: unlike some languages I could mention, they don't feel like random collections of letters.  So when Python complains of the comparison

```
if x > 0:
```

that

```
TypeError: no ordering relation is defined for complex numbers
```

you should take it at its word: you're trying to compare a complex number `x` to see whether or not it's greater than zero, and Python doesn't know how to order complex numbers.  Is `2j > 0`?  Is `-2j > 0`?  Etc.  In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.

Now, in your particular case, you've already branched on whether or not `x.imag != 0`, so you know that `x.imag == 0` when you're testing `x` and you can simply take the real part, IIUC:

```
>>> x = 3+0j
>>> type(x)
<type 'complex'>
>>> x > 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-9-36cf1355a74b>", line 1, in <module>
    x > 0
TypeError: no ordering relation is defined for complex numbers

>>> x.real > 0
True
```

Comment: I already have the cube root function (shown in the other question) set to handle complex numbers. This shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: user2330618: no, you don't.  Have it set to handle complex numbers, I mean.  Right before the `if x < 0:`, add `print(type(x), repr(x))`, to convince yourself `x` is a complex number.  Then pick a random complex number, say `2+3j`, and type `2+3j > 0` at the console.  Note the error message.

Comment: I think, then, that it would be failing only for complex numbers whose imaginary part is zero. But I can definitely fix that with: elif x.imag == 0: x = x.real

Comment: Erm, that's exactly what I said: "you can simply take the real part", because "you know that `x.imag == 0`".

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear from your example code what `x` is, but it seems it must be a complex number.  Sometimes, when using complex numerical methods, an approximate solution will come up as a complex number even though the exact solution is supposed to be real.

Complex numbers have no natural ordering, so an inequality `x > 0` makes no sense if `x` is complex.  That's what the type error is about.